# Compute a kind of symbolic integral

Tags: definite-integrals, symbolic-computation

I have to handle a class of symbolic integral with the form, more precisely,

When I set $u(x,t) = e^{-t}x^2(1-x)^2$, then how to compute
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\int^{t}_0\frac{\partial u(x,\eta)}{\partial \eta}\frac{d\eta}{(t - \eta)^{\alpha}}
\end{equation}
and if we set $u(x,t) = \sin(t+1)x^3(1-x)^3$, again, how to compute $I$, 
are there some tips for handling this kind of symbolic integral ?

Comment: This is essentially the integral $\int_0^td\eta e^{-\eta} (t-\eta)^{\alpha}$. I would suggest to look at the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).